# Define variable in init, set the variable in get method, and use it in post method

Tags: python, init

I am setting a variable in my init method as an empty list. Then, in my get method, I query the database and set the list. Next, in my post method, I am trying to use the variable. But, for some reason, the variable is set back to an empty list when my post method runs(which may be completely expected?). Could you help me figure out what I am doing wrong or let me know if there is an alternative way to do this?

Thanks!

```
class thisHandler(BaseHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(thisHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.topList= []

    def get(self, id):
        if self.user:
            #Other stuff happens
            self.topList = get_myList(id) #This is definitely returning a populated list as it displays just fine on my page
            #Other stuff happens
            self.render('page.html', variables)

    def post(self, id):
        #Other stuff happens
        system.debug(self.topList) #this comes back empty. this is the first reference to it in the post method
        #Other stuff happens
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods are not being called in the same thread of execution. Your instance data is thread-local. If you want data to persist from one remote call to the next, you will need to store session data on the server side, using some type of cookie to identify the client session from one call to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the methods `get` or `set`, always stick to their meaning. Never set/update any variable in get method and never return any value from set method. I have seen lot of people doing that.

Right way:

```
GET method - should always return what you want
SET method - should always set the values and never return anything
```

With that being said, you need to call the method `self.get()` before going to the `post()` method. This helps in updating the value.